# Print output of parallel kernels to console

Tags: output-formatting, parallelization

Is it possible to print all the output (inside a Print[] command) of a parallelized computation to the console? I can't find a control for this. I find that my computer can handle printing to the console much better than printing to the notebook.

Thanks

Comment: Just put your computation in a .m script and execute it from teh console via `wolfram -script <scriptname.m>`. Don't forget to set `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType->OutputForm];` at the beginning of the script

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried what you suggested with a test file, reading

`SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm];
ParallelDo[Print[i], {i, 1, 10}];`

wolfram -script doesn't work for me, but math -script does. However, nothing appears, the command seems to just finish without producing output.

Comment: The following code works for me: `echo 'SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]; ParallelDo[Print[i], {i, 1, 10}];' > /tmp/test.m; math -script /tmp/test.m`. Which version of *Mathematica* do you have?

Comment: Yes, that works for me too. I found the mistake... In the notebook my cells were not initialization cells, so in the created .m file all the lines were commented out. I changed that and it works fine, thank you!