# Print messages of parallel kernels to console

Tags: parallelization, message-coding

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136585/52619) shows how to print output to the console, but how about messages?

For the main kernel, I know this way:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, MessageOptions -> {"KernelMessageAction" -> "PrintToConsole"}]
```

But if used in `Parallelize`, I am returned

> SetOptions::optnf :  MessageOptions is not a known option for Null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "console" means the Messages notebook window (and not, say, stdout when run in a terminal session), try something like the following

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, MessageOptions -> {"KernelMessageAction" -> "PrintToConsole"}]

$KernelCount; (* load the Parallel` code *)

Unprotect[MessagePacket]; (* patch MessagePacket upvalue *)

MessagePacket /: 
 Parallel`Protected`PacketHandler[
  t : MessagePacket[sym_, tag_, text_], Parallel`Kernels`kernel_] := 
 NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[], 
  Cell[text, "Message", "MSG", 
   CellLabel -> Parallel`Kernels`Private`kernelString[Parallel`Kernels`kernel], 
   ShowCellLabel -> True]]

ParallelEvaluate[1/0]

(* {ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity} *)
```

[image]